# Возврат параметров в Exception

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rxjava2

Метод **itemRepository.sendItem(it.item!!)** возвращает

```
Flowable<Response<Item>>
```

Как сделать чтобы если при выполнении itemRepository.sendItem возникнет ошибка, в Throwable чтобы падали входные параметры из sendItem ? Возможно ли?

```
var itemId: String? = null

DataBase.getInstance(applicationContext)?.hisrorysDao()!!.getHistorys()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())              
                .map { it.sortedBy { it.itemErrors?.size  }
                    return@map it
                }
                .flatMapIterable { it-> it }
                .flatMap {
                    itemId = it.item!!.id
                    itemRepository.sendItem(it.item!!)
                }
                .subscribe({

                }, {
                   //при ошибки необходимо записать ошибку 
                   //и пойти дальше т.е. попытаться отправить данные для следующего значения itemRepository.sendItem(it.item!!) в flatMap
                    saveErr(itemId, it.toString())//сохранили ошибку для itemId
                })
```

Суть в том что, если при отправки будет сбой то нужно в базу записать событие ошибки для отправляемого значения.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял из вашего вопроса вы хотите обработать результат получения данных из базы. Предлагаю вам посмотреть на простейший Observable - [Single](http://reactivex.io/documentation/single.html). У него есть 2 метода:

**onSuccess**

```
Собственно сам результат
```

**onError**

```
исключение(или ошибка, как угодно)
```

Вот [пример](https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/109184/) использования